# install docker container - docker run - invalid reference format

Tags: docker, nominatim

From the docker quickstart terminal on Windows 7 64-bit, I'm following the instructions to install [this docker container](https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker). I run the command,

```
docker run http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/nominatim
```

and I get this error:

```
c:\program files\docker toolbox\docker.exe: invald reference format.
```

I can't find any information about this error related to this container.

Comment: first pull the image, then run the container, i think you need to execute http:// inside the docker container. not as an argument to docker, so it is invalid.

Comment: if the answer solves your problem please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image name that you have specified to pull and run is wrong. The image name should be `mediagis/nominatim`.

Your docker run command should be

```
docker run mediagis/nominatim
```

It is **not necessary to pull the image first and run it**. By default docker run first tries to find such image in your machine if not then it tries to download from docker repository.

If you specify URL format it directly downloads from private repo if such image is not found in your machine.

**Brief Explanation:**

Docker takes whatever that is in form of url as an image and the reason for this is sometimes you may want to run image from your private repository.  So here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/nominatim is considered as an **image** called `wiki/nominatim`  from a **private repo** called `wiki.openstreetmap.org` by docker and the format of private repo and image is wrong . It should be `<domain.com>/image:tag` where `tag` is optional. You are not supposed to provide protocol **(http://)**. [See this for reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub) Hence the error is thrown as invalid reference format.

If you would have given as `docker run wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/nominatim` it would have tried to download image called `wiki/nominatim` from `wiki.openstreetmap.org` private repo with `latest` tag. Since no such repo and image exists it reports **Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 404 response body** as the url throws `404: Not Found` when docker daemon tries connecting to it.

References:

1. [Pull an image from Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub)
2. [Pull from a different registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry)
3. [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)
4. [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

***Note: Unless you specify tag name which is optional docker always downloads `latest` tag from repo.***

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull the image first , then run the container.  according to your docker command, you are trying to access a website, it is not a docker container image. so that's why it is giving you the invalid reference format.

Answer (score 1):

docker run http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/nominatim

does non make any sense syntactically ...

In any case the correct command to get the latest image is:

sudo docker pull mediagis/nominatim:3.1

Notice that each version has its own installation instructions (versions prior to 3.1 were structurally different), so please do refer to the appropriate section:

https://hub.docker.com/r/mediagis/nominatim/tags/

However I do agree with you that

docker run --restart=always -p 6432:5432 -p 7070:8080 -d -v /home/me/nominatimdata/postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main nominatim sh /app/start.sh

Should be

docker run --restart=always -p 6432:5432 -p 7070:8080 -d -v /home/me/nominatimdata/postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main mediagis/nominatim sh /app/start.sh

instead. The installation instructions need updating there.